# Logic value of a single input pin into a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, microchip, assembly

I'm trying to get the logic value from a node in a circuit (it is the output of a comparator that can either be 0V or 5V) into an [AT89S51](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/77367/ATMEL/AT89S51.html) microcontroller. My program just tries to get the value of pin P0.0 into the accumulator (considering that 5V would be 1).

Assembly code:

```
org 0x00
mov a, p0.0
end
```

but it is giving me the error

```
ERROR #13 test.asm: Expression is wrong type.
```

I tried searching for a way to do this but couldn't find any reference on why it is not working.
How can I get the value of the input pin P0.1? I thought of getting all of the P0 port and just check if it is #00000001b. But this limits my action since I'm obligated to have all other pins of port P0 to L.

Comment: The port pins can be any mix of input or output. Port 0 is an open drain port so you may need a pullup on your input.

Comment: I realize this already has an accepted answer, but in the MCS51 architecture you can move a single bit to the C.  The instruction "mov a, p0.0" is invalid because you're trying to move 1 bit into an 8 bit register.  Instead, use "clr acc; mov c,p0.0; mov acc.0,c" to accomplish this.  You can also use "jb p0.0,foo" or "jnb p0.0,foo" to test the pin directly.

Comment: FWIW C is a thing.  It's probably what you want in the long term. It's probably what you want in the short term too, if you want to sleep.  (Assembly is great and I used it exlusively for 8-bitters for a long time.  My code is now not only readable: it's *faster*.  Your compiler is only a mediocre compiler, but you're a rubbish compiler.  (That said maybe you're learning ASM, which is a good thing to do, or you're writing an ISR or something... but even then you'd be surprised how good a compiler can be)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, if the MCU has no mechanism of reading just one bit, you read the whole port and mask off the irrelevant bits you want to ignore to zero and then compare if the remaining bit makes the result zero or non-zero.

Answer (score 8):

> How can I get the value of the input pin P0.1?

You may "jump" on a bit value (e.g. JB, JNB): [ISA](https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/atmel/at_c51ism.pdf)

[image]

> But this limits my action since I'm obligated to have all other pins of port P0 to L.

Not really. You can read the whole port and mask the bit you need to check with an AND operation.